# string replacement on koRpus treetag

Tags: r, tokenize, treetagger, korpus

The function

```
tokenize("C:\\test_treetag.txt", clean.raw=list("aren't"="are not"))
```

allows me to tokenize and replace "aren't" by the tokens "are not"

I'm trying to do the same in the function in the **treetag** function.